# linq max and min date

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having some problems porting this SQL SP into a linq statement. The sql logic is basic get the min and max StartDate and if they are equal  use the min date value for MeetingDate. MeetingDate is a string so I would tostring it MM/dd/yyyy. If they are not equal  then concat both min StartDate and max StartDate together .

```
LINQ
    var Meeting = (from m in db.Meetings
    join md in db.MeetingDates on m.MeetingId equals md.MeetingId
    join mf in db.MeetingFiles on m.MeetingId equals mf.MeetingId
    join fm in db.FileManagers on mf.FileManagerId equals fm.FileManagerId
    join vwGP in db.vwGuidelinePanels on m.GroupId equals vwGP.GroupId
    where mf.FileCategoryItemDictionaryId == 755
    select new Model.Meeting
    {
    MeetingId = m.MeetingId,
    GroupId = m.GroupId,
    MeetingDate =  max(md.StartDate) == min(md.StartDate)? min(md.StartDate)
    min(md.StartDate) + ' - ' + max(md.StartDate)
    }).ToList();


SQL
    case 
        when Convert(varchar(10),min(md.StartDate),101)=Convert(varchar(10),max(md.StartDate),101) 
        then Convert(varchar(10),min(md.StartDate),101) 
    else 
    Convert(varchar(10),min(md.StartDate),101)+' - '+Convert(varchar(10),max(md.StartDate),101) end
```

output

```
04/15/2010
05/06/2010
05/12/2010
06/13/2010 - 06/16/2010
06/16/2010 - 06/19/2010
```

using the max and min there is a runtime error

[image]

Comment: "add both min StartDate and max StartDate together" - what do you mean by that? What data type are you expecting the result to be? It looks like you might be trying to get a text based result, but then the min date value isn't a string...

Comment: something like this 08/06/2010 - 08/09/2010

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here but I see one issue. `min(md.StartDate)` would be a `DateTime` type and the subtraction of `min(md.StartDate) + ' - ' + max(md.StartDate)` would be a `TimeSpan` type.

Comment: would i just convert min(md.StartDate) into a string

Comment: Right - so please clarify that in the question. You don't want to "use the min date value for MeetingDate" - you want to convert min date value into a string. You should probably start by applying that change into your LINQ... as well as telling us what the actual problem is. (You've shown us some LINQ, but not described in what way it's not working for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is `min(md.StartDate)` would be a `DateTime` type and the subtraction of `min(md.StartDate) + ' - ' + max(md.StartDate)` would be a `TimeSpan` type. If you want the output how you have it then converting to a `string` would probably be the best choice. Rough untested example below. I have updated my answer to use the correct LINQ syntax. Yet again this is untested.

```
MeetingDate = md.StartDate.Max() == md.StartDate.Min()? md.StartDate.Min().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy} - {1: MM/dd/yyyy}", md.StartDate.Min(), md.StartDate.Max());
```

Comment: Thanks any idea why I am getting max/min does not exits?

Comment: In short, because it doesn't. Not like that in Linq.

Comment: Actually, I found a post that might help with the Min and Max in LINQ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423656/group-by-and-min-in-linq

Comment: So I would not have it in the  select new Model.Meeting section?